# Reload reCaptcha after ajaxComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

My reCaptcha is not reloading when ajaxComplete event complete.

I have a console error: "No reCAPTCHA clients exist." So why my reCaptcha client disappeared after ajaxComplete?

Here is my sample code:

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
         grecaptcha.reset(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `grecaptcha.render('recaptchaId');` solved the problem.

So, the updated code is:

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
         grecaptcha.render('recaptchaWıdgetId'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly stated in the exception. You need to render reCaptcha on the page with `grecaptcha.render`:

```js
var domId = 'recaptchaId';
grecaptcha.render(domId, {"sitekey": "YOUR_CAPTCHA_ID", size: 'invisible'});
```

In my case error came from minified code:

```js
if (y[6](57).contains(window.___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[P].Ci)){
  Y=P;
  break a
}
throw Error("No reCAPTCHA clients exist.");
```

and `window.___grecaptcha_cfg.clients` was empty till I fixed the order: `render` is called before `execute`.