# Error: No reCAPTCHA clients exist (reCAPTCHA v3)

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I've integrated reCAPTCHA v3 in one of my forms. In onload, there's a token produced and google captcha logo in the bottom right corner. But when I submit the form, in console there is an error shown, "Error: No reCAPTCHA clients exist". Also, it seems, no data is fetched by "g-recaptcha-response" and $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"] remains empty.

Here is the sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ReCaptchaCallbackV3 = function() {
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute("site_key").then(function(token) {
                console.log("v3 Token: " + token);
            });
        });
    };
</script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=ReCaptchaCallbackV3&render=site_key"></script>
```

It doesn't produce any "g-recaptcha-response" when the form is submitted.

I don't know much about google reCaptcha. I've followed the documentation provided by them and used a site and a secret key in the proper way.

Can anybody please tell me where might be the problem and what is the possible solution?

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927941/reload-recaptcha-after-ajaxcomplete

Comment: Is it possible to have an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927941/reload-recaptcha-after-ajaxcomplete. The problem still there. @NinoFiliu, code snippet added.

Comment: in my case I was providing wrong recaptcha site key :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried loading the script before trying to send the request?

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=ReCaptchaCallbackV3&render=site_key"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ReCaptchaCallbackV3 = function() {
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute("site_key").then(function(token) {
                console.log("v3 Token: " + token);
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 23):

I believe this error occurs when the reCaptcha api.js loads, but your container is not present on the page yet (at least for v2). I had this error occur in a React app when I navigated to the page rather than loading it as the first on. Instead of using `render=explicit` and using a global namespace `onLoadCallback`, I was able to resolve it by rendering the captcha element manually.

Instead of creating a `<div class="g-recaptcha"></div>`, give the container div an id only (`<div id="recaptcha-container"></div>`) and render  it in your JS code (e.g. in `componentDidMount` for a React app):

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
  grecaptcha.render("recaptcha-container", {
    "sitekey": "your-site-key"
  });
});
```

Comment: To give some more color to this, you also don't even have to specify an id; you can pass a reference to the HTML element (e.g. an angular `ElementRef`'s `nativeElement`).

Answer (score 12):

When I came across this problem with reCAPTCHA v3, it was because I didn't pass it the correct site key.

Comment: Yes, for me i was passing undefined by mistake. The error should be more descriptive in this case, but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: Same for us @ehab, we were passing undefined by mistake. The error should be more descriptive in this case, but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: Can't believe this was my issue.. What an unhelpful message.

Answer (score 2):

This also happens in Recaptcha 2 before user interacts with it. So, I have a submit button that triggers a JS function that checks the value of recaptcha. To solve the no client exists problem, I did:

```
try {
   data["reCaptcha"] = grecaptcha.getResponse();
} catch (err) {
   data["reCaptcha"] = "";
}
```

The data object then gets sent to a back-end script that validates the recaptcha. The back-end also checks for the field being empty.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I was calling `grecaptcha.reset();` when there wasn't any Recaptcha active on the site

```
grecaptcha.reset();
recaptcha__en.js:507 Uncaught Error: No reCAPTCHA clients exist.
    at MX (recaptcha__en.js:507)
    at Object.Zn [as reset] (recaptcha__en.js:514)
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Comment: We had a legacy V2 code and .reset() is not even mentioned in V3 docs

Comment: I use v3. if i want to re-gen, reset i need to call function window.grecaptcha.execute again to reset

Answer (score 1):

I was using React and only rendering my captcha container sometimes. Fixed by hiding the captcha button instead of not rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `grecaptcha.reset();` was present from previous code snippet, and I was programmatically invoking it.

As the captcha verification is going on the fly every time. Resetting wasn't required.
After eliminating this `grecaptcha.reset();` my code works perfectly fine.

Maybe this hint can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

We received this because we have a second environment with another domain and forgot to add this domain to the reCaptcha admin site. The solution was to add the new domain to the settings.
The steps are
Open www.google/recaptcha/admin/site
Select the site you're working on
Click on the settings gear
Add the domain in its respective section

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm as user @Piyush Pranjal said, removing it works in V3, upon re'executing the function that is protected by captcha, a new captcha key is provided.